# Is "I should be in by 11.00 AM" grammaticaly correct?

Tags: grammar

Today I got an e-mail from a guy I had a meeting. He was late and he wrote me "I should be in by 11". I understood what he meant but I wonder is this sentence grammatically correct or not ? I never saw such a usage for "in" and using "in" and "by" together seems to me a little bit suspicious.

Comment: Have you looked up _in_ in a dictionary, specifically the uses labelled as ‘adverb’ (it’s not actually an adverb, but most dictionaries call prepositions with no object adverbs)? This is a perfectly normal usage of _in_ that can be found in any dictionary, which I’m afraid makes your question off-topic here.

Comment: Don't worry about ***every*** pair of consecutive words; for example, "guy I" (in your first sentence) is not a common phrase, but the sentence as a whole works.  (Well, actually, it's a bit awkward, but never mind that.)  Do you understand what it means to use "by" together with a time?

Comment: @Scott , I guess I do: it means I am going  to be there starting from 11.00 AM ? :)

Comment: "by" a stated time means *at* that time ***or before**.*  For example, "I need that report *by 3:00.*"  Arguably, if the guy came in at 10:00 and left at 10:30, he could say "I was in by 11:00."  If you don't understand that, you might do better at the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence you gave, *in* is not used as a preposition but as an adjective:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 [predicative] Present at one's home or office.
>
> ‘we knocked at the door but there was no one in’

*[definition from oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)*

It becomes more apparent if you move *by 11* to the beginning of the sentence:

> By 11, I should be in.

Or if you replace the time with something else:

> I should be in when they arrive.

The sentence is grammatically correct.